# Load XML into CLR Objects via LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have some XML that I have loaded into an XDocument. My XML looks like the following:

```
<Items>
  <Item Date="11/22/2010 9:05:23 PM" />
  <Item Date="11/22/2010 9:05:39 PM" />
</Items>
```

Each `Item` contains a `DateTime`. I am loading this XML into an XDocument using the following code:

```
string s = GetXml();
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(s);
```

I am trying to figure out how to load the `Items` into a `List<DateTime>`. Can somebody explain to me how to do this using LINQ and C#?

Thank you!

Comment: The document, as is, is not valid XML. What are those backslashes before double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but something like this should do the trick:

```
var list = (from item in xml.Root.Descendents("Item")
           select DateTime.Parse(item.Attribute("Date").Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = xml.Root.Elements("Item").
                Select(item => DateTime.Parse(item.Attribute("Date").Value));

List<DateTime> result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following statement to create a list of Dates, you can use the explicit cast from [XElement to DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343203.aspx) instead of using DateTime.Parse

```
var dates = xml.Root.Elements("Item")
                    .Select(e => (DateTime)e.Attribute("Date")).ToList();
```